# Prevent pandas read_csv treating first row as header of column names

Tags: python, pandas, csv, header-row

I'm reading in a `pandas DataFrame` using `pd.read_csv`. I want to keep the first row as data, however it keeps getting converted to column names.

- I tried `header=False` but this just deleted it entirely.

(Note on my input data: I have a string (`st = '\n'.join(lst)`) that I convert to a file-like object (`io.StringIO(st)`), then build the `csv` from that file object.)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You want `header=None` the `False` gets type promoted to `int` into `0` see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) emphasis mine:

> header : int or list of ints, default ‘infer’ Row number(s) to use as
>   the column names, and the start of the data. Default behavior is as if
>   set to 0 if no names passed, otherwise **None**. Explicitly pass header=0
>   to be able to replace existing names. The header can be a list of
>   integers that specify row locations for a multi-index on the columns
>   e.g. [0,1,3]. Intervening rows that are not specified will be skipped
>   (e.g. 2 in this example is skipped). Note that this parameter ignores
>   commented lines and empty lines if skip_blank_lines=True, so header=0
>   denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file.

You can see the difference in behaviour, first with `header=0`:

```
In [95]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""a,b,c
0,1,2
3,4,5"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=0)

Out[95]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
```

Now with `None`:

```
In [96]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None)

Out[96]:
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
1  0  1  2
2  3  4  5
```

Note that in latest version `0.19.1`, this will now raise a `TypeError`:

```
In [98]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=False)
```

> TypeError: Passing a bool to header is invalid. Use header=None for no
>   header or header=int or list-like of ints to specify the row(s) making
>   up the column names

Answer (score 10):

I think you need parameter `header=None` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""a,b
2,1
1,1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),header=None)
print (df)
   0  1
0  a  b
1  2  1
2  1  1
```

Comment: This just removes the first row altogether, it doesn't treat it as numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `pd.ExcelFile` to read all the excel file sheets then:

```
df = pd.ExcelFile("path_to_file.xlsx")    
df.sheet_names                       # Provide the sheet names in the excel file

df = df.parse(2, header=None)        # Parsing the 2nd sheet in the file with header = None
df
```

Output:

```
   0  1  
0  a  b
1  1  1
2  0  1
3  5  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom column name in order to prevent this:

Let say if you have two columns in your dataset then:

```
df = pd.read_csv(your_file_path, names = ['first column', 'second column'])
```

You can also generate programmatically column names if you have more than and can pass a list in front of names attribute.