# When loading CSV data with pandas, the first line is mistaken for the title

Tags: python, pandas, csv, header, header-row

How to prevent the following? When I load a file with `pd.read_csv()`, the first line gets unwantedly treated as a header (list of column names):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('namefile',sep=' ')
print(data)
```

and only the second line onwards gets treated as the data (`vector = np.array(data)`).

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files,

Comment: `pd.read_csv(..., header=None)` as the doc says. (See the doc for more complex or multiline headers)

Comment: Duplicate of [Prevent pandas read_csv treating first row as header of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769691/prevent-pandas-read-csv-treating-first-row-as-header-of-column-names) and tons of others

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231664/4909087) for a cheatsheet of useful `read_csv` arguments you should know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the option of header to exclude columns `data=pd.read_csv('namefile',sep=' ', header =None)`