# How to convert Top Row google sheet to index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

sample not have ,header=0

```
dfGetMoniter = pd.DataFrame(data=gc.open("Data").worksheet("Moniter").get_all_values())

for index, row in dfGetMoniter.iterrows():

    print(index)
```

out put

```
0
1
2
3
```

but i want to show header Top Row of google sheet like this

```
A
B
C
D
```

[image]

and i try put ,header=0 like [pd.read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769691/prevent-pandas-read-csv-treating-first-row-as-header-of-column-names) and got error

```
dfGetMoniter = pd.DataFrame(data=gc.open("Data").worksheet("Moniter").get_all_values(),header=0)

for index, row in dfGetMoniter.iterrows():

    print(index)
```

```
E:\PycharmProjects\exsample\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/PycharmProjects/exsample/BinanceTutorialVideo-master/now/sheetManager.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PycharmProjects/exsample/BinanceTutorialVideo-master/now/sheetManager.py", line 16, in <module>
    dfGetMoniter = pd.DataFrame(data=gc.open("Data").worksheet("Moniter").get_all_values(),header=0)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

edit change

```
for col in dfGetMoniter.columns:
    print(col)
```

not work
[image]

Comment: Do you want to transpose your dataset? Why do you want the header to be output vertically?

Comment: No output vertically i just want out header name from google sheet first row i wan to get colum name ANT,BAT,CAT,DOG  Not out put 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

A dataframe's columns are available from the `columns` attribute:

```
dfGetMoniter.columns

Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

```
for col in dfGetMoniter.columns:
    print(col)

A
B
C
D
```

Take a look at the [introductory tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/02_read_write.html#min-tut-02-read-write).